# Problems with removing active class

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've got two wp menus:

First one:

```
<nav id="navigation" role="navigation" class="fir-nav">
    <section class="menus first-menu">
        <h3>Pagrindinis</h3>
        <ul id="main-nav" class="nav">
            <li id="menu-item-4" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-4"><a href="#apiev">About Tim</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-5" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-5 menulink-active"><a href="#about">Tim</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-6" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-6"><a href="#somthhi">Lalallala</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-52" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-52"><a href="#blog">BLog 1</a></li>
        </ul>
    </section><!--/.menus-->
    <a href="#top" class="nav-close"><span>Return to Content</span></a>
</nav>
```

Second one:

```
<nav class="sec-nav" id="navigation">
    <section class="menus second-menu">
        <ul id="main-nav" class="nav">
            <li id="menu-item-23" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-23"><a href="#blog2">Blog 2</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-24" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-24 menulink-active"><a href="#galery">Gal</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-25" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-25"><a href="#blog">Blog</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-51" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-51"><a href="#reg">Reg</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-80" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-80"><a href="#contac">Contac</a></li>
        </ul>
    </section><!--/.menus-->                    
</nav>
```

And I've got this script:

```
    jQuery(this).closest('li').addClass('menulink-active').siblings().removeClass('menulink-active');
```

It puts active class for link. But when I press the link of the second menu it doesn't remove the link from the first menu. What can I do?

Comment: Provide more of the JS code. Where is your line of code called? Who is `this`?

Comment: Improved lay-out of code a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First remove the Active class then add it to current clicked `li`.

```js
$(function(){
  
  $("li").on("click",function(){
     $(this).siblings().removeClass('menulink-active');
     $(this).addClass('menulink-active');
    });
  });
```

```css
.menulink-active{
  background-color:green;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="sec-nav" id="navigation">
    <section class="menus second-menu">
        <ul id="main-nav" class="nav">
            <li id="menu-item-23" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-23"><a href="#blog2">Blog 2</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-24" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-24 menulink-active"><a href="#galery">Gal</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-25" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-25"><a href="#blog">Blog</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-51" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-51"><a href="#reg">Reg</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-80" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-80"><a href="#contac">Contac</a></li>
        </ul>
    </section><!--/.menus-->                    
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove class from all li elements and then add it to last clicked

```
$('a').click(function() {
    $('li').removeClass('menulink-active');
    $(this).closest('li').addClass('menulink-active');
});
```

// Btw do you have two navs with id "navigation"? ID must be unique, you can't use same id twice

Answer (score 0):

```js
 $('li').click(function() {

   $(this).closest('ul').children().removeClass('menulink-active');
   $(this).addClass('menulink-active');


 });
```

```css
.menulink-active {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav id="navigation" role="navigation" class="fir-nav">
  <section class="menus first-menu">
    <h3>Pagrindinis</h3>
    <ul id="main-nav" class="nav">
      <li id="menu-item-4" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-4"><a href="#apiev">About Tim</a>
      </li>
      <li id="menu-item-5" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-5 menulink-active"><a href="#about">Tim</a>
      </li>
      <li id="menu-item-6" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-6"><a href="#somthhi">Lalallala</a>
      </li>
      <li id="menu-item-52" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-52"><a href="#blog">BLog 1</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </section>
  <!--/.menus-->
  <a href="#top" class="nav-close"><span>Return to Content</span></a>
</nav>




<nav class="sec-nav" id="navigation">
  <section class="menus second-menu">
    <ul id="main-nav" class="nav">
      <li id="menu-item-23" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-23"><a href="#blog2">Blog 2</a>
      </li>
      <li id="menu-item-24" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-24 menulink-active"><a href="#galery">Gal</a>
      </li>
      <li id="menu-item-25" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-25"><a href="#blog">Blog</a>
      </li>
      <li id="menu-item-51" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-51"><a href="#reg">Reg</a>
      </li>
      <li id="menu-item-80" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-80"><a href="#contac">Contac</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </section>
  <!--/.menus-->
</nav>
```